# SQL same unit between two tables needs order numbers in 1 cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-group-concat

I have 2 tables:

```
SELECT UnitId FROM dbo.tblUnits

SELECT UnitId, WorkOrderNumber FROM dbo.tblWorkOrders
```

I need to display all UnitId's from dbo.tblUnits then in 1 column diplay all the WorkOrders seperated by a comma.

So here is some sample data:
dbo.tblUnits:

```
UnitId
123
156
178
```

dbo.tblWorkOrders

```
UnitId WorkOrderNumber
123        1
123        2
156        4
178        5
178        9
178        10
```

I have to use the tblUnits table because I am pulling more data from it but the final result I want to show this:

```
UnitId   WorkOrderNumber
123         1,2
156         4 
178         5,9,10
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197626/concatenate-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 
    UnitId, 
    stuff((select ', ' + convert(varchar, WorkOrderNumber) 
           from tblWorkOrders t2 where t1.UnitId = t2.UnitId 
           for xml path('')),
          1,2,'') WorkOrderNumbers
from tblWorkOrders t1
group by UnitId
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   t1.UnitId,
   substring((SELECT ( ', ' + WorkOrderNumber)
                           FROM tblWorkOrders t2
                           WHERE t1.UnitId= t2.UnitId
                           ORDER BY 
                              UnitId
                           FOR XML PATH( '' )
                          ), 3, 1000 ) as WorkOrderNumbers
FROM tblWorkOrders as t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this nice article about this very topic.  It shows you different way to do this.

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    UnitId, 
    STRING_AGG(WorkOrderNumber, ',')
FROM dbo.tblWorkOrders
GROUP BY UnitId
```

should give you the final result you showed.