# T-sql query to output the values in CSV format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a values in a table as shown below.  I need to get the **`generation times`** in comma seperated values for each **`subscriptionID`**.

### SubscriptionID GenerationTimes

```
6519    NULL
6616    NULL
6617    NULL
6618    9:00:00
6618    17:00:00
6634    NULL
6698    0:00:00
```

I need the result as follows

### SubscriptionID GenerationTimes

```
6519    NULL
6616    NULL
6617    NULL
6618    9:00, 17:00
6634    NULL
6698    0:00:00
```

you notice for subscriptionID **6618** there are two generation times and so I have to put them in one row with comma ',' separated.  Please give me suggestion how i can write the T-sql statement.

Comment: Why do you even *have* comma-separated values in a relational database?

Comment: @Tomalak OP wants result to be comma-separated, that is not how the data is stored

Comment: @tclausen.dk: Ah, I see.

Comment: actually i have to show the result on SSRS report with comma seperated values using the result set which i get from the Stored procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use for xml path like so:

```
select 
      t1.SubscriptionID,
      (select GenerationTimes + ', '
       from tableName t2
       where t1.SubscriptionID = t2.SubscriptionID
       for xml path('')) as GenerationTimes
from tableName t1
group by t1.SubscriptionID
```

Comment: Thanks Aducci,  It is very simple using xml path.  I can straight away use this as t-sql statement instead using a seperate function to get the result.

Comment: Even though the time values in this question will not include "special characters", this is not the best way to use XML for concatenation. Special XML characters like `>`, `<`, `&`, etc will be expanded to: `&gt;`, `&lt;`, `&amp;`.  Here is a very similar, yet better method to prevent this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413627/concatenate-column-values-for-rows-with-the-same-values-of-different-columns/6413796#6413796  This isn't really an issue for the data in this particular case, but it is best to learn a method that will work on all of your data, so you won't get burned later.