# Aggregate/concatenate values from a column into a single row

Tags: sql-server

I have a couple thousand franchises, and about 3 or 4 service groups. The service groups are in a separate table, then i have third table joining them together. A franchise may be connected to 1 or many service groups. What I am trying to achieve is listing out the franchises, with a column labeled "Service Categories". It would then be a comma separated list of which services they provide. So right now, here's my output:

```
id  Service Groups     name                    email                address      City         State
1   Cleaning Services  Franchise of LocationX  example@example.com  123 Fake st. Springfield  TheOneTheSimpsonsLiveIn
2   Disaster Services  Franchise of LocationX  example@example.com  123 Fake st. Springfield  TheOneTheSimpsonsLiveIn
```

I would like to have it so it becomes this:

```
id  Service Groups                        name                    email                address      City         State
1   Cleaning Services, Disaster Services  Franchise of LocationX  example@example.com  123 Fake st. Springfield  TheOneTheSimpsonsLiveIn
```

Any suggestions or references of methods/functions I can use to do this would be greately appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You may take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344950/sql-query-to-get-aggregated-result-in-comma-seperators-along-with-group-by-column/6349132#6349132

Comment: Refer this post
[http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/25/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column/](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/25/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column/)

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874966/concatenate-row-values-t-sql

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

Comment: @ypercube That post helped me out. Thanks. Post your answer and ill accept.

Comment: No need for that. You can post your solution as answer (and accept it) if you feel it may help others.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Declare @TempServiceGroups varchar(max)=''
Select COALESCE(@TempServiceGroups,'')+ServiceGroups+',' from MyTable
Select @TempServiceGroups AS ServiceGroups , Name,Email,Address,City,State
from MyTable
```

Comment: Gave it a shot. The service groups column now just has commas at the end. They aren't combined :(