# Combine Specific Column Value with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

is there anywhere to get values like this?

from

```
id        column_1        column_2
1         abc             hello 
1         abc             world
```

to

```
id        column_1        column_2
1         abc             hello world
```

Thanks alot :)

Comment: Yes, but it's horribly inefficient compared to designing your schema better, or letting the presentation layer do it rather than the database layer :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo thanks, canyou provide me solution?

Comment: @andrain thanks, may this use for mssql?

Comment: Does an ID always correspond to the same column_1 value or? i.e. can you have 1 for ID and 'def' for column_1? Regardless this can be done with XML Path with an empty string and a group by clause. The example provided by Adrian is perfect

Comment: @Adrian Dude, stop spamming the same link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm on my phone and my answer kept going as comment. I'll try to get rid of those

Comment: How do you know that these two values will be combined to `Hello World` and not to `World Hello` ?? I don't see any "sequence" in there.....

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that a given value in column_1 doesn't always correspond to the same value in ID and vice versa.

```
DECLARE @temptable TABLE (id integer, column_1 varchar(20), column_2 varchar(20))

INSERT into @temptable 
select 1 ,'abc' ,'hello' 
UNION 
select 1 ,'abc','world' 
union 
select 1, 'def', 'blah' 
union 
select 2, 'abc', 'world'
union
select 2, 'abc', 'blah'

select id, column_1, 
(SELECT column_2 + ' ' 
 FROM @temptable t2
    where t2.id = t1.id and t2.column_1 = t1.column_1
 FOR XML PATH('') 
 ) new_column_2 
from @temptable t1
group by id, column_1
```

Results:

```
id  column_1    new_column_2
1   abc         hello world 
1   def         blah 
2   abc         blah world
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql, you can use **GROUP_CONCAT**, something like this:

```
SELECT id, column_1, GROUP_CONCAT(column2 SEPARATOR ' ') FROM some_table GROUP BY id, column_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be quite literal about it:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id integer, column_1 varchar(20), column_2 varchar(20))

INSERT into @t
    SELECT 1 ,'abc' ,'hello' 
    UNION  
    SELECT 1 ,'abc','world' 

SELECT DISTINCT 
     id, column_1, 
     (SELECT column_2 + ' ' FROM @t FOR XML PATH('') ) column_2 
FROM @t
```

Comment: I am sure this table has more data in it than just the two rows. With your query, the column_2 column will display the values of every row in column_2 concatenated together for every combination of id and column_1, which I am sure is not what the original poster wants.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server, you use the FOR XMLcontruct for that.

Look at this example here:

[SQL Query to get aggregated result in comma seperators along with group by column in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344950/sql-query-to-get-aggregated-result-in-comma-seperators-along-with-group-by-column/6348414#6348414)