# SQL: aggregate a joined table's id's into a string

Tags: sql, join, csv, export

I need to export data from a SQL database (some groups use SQL Server, some Oracle, etc.) into a CSV where I need the id's from the joined table in a string.

For example, I have a table of Classes and a table of Students. From Classes, I need ID, Name, Section, Time, and from Students I need a string of the ID's of Students in the class. The results would return the columns: id,name,section,time,student_ids. The 'student_ids' column should be a delimited string, such as:

```
'32,43,53,12,41'
```

The row output would end up being something like:

```
"1405,Computer Science,101,12-1:30,'32,43,53,12,41'"
```

The number of Students per Class is not consistent, there could be one Student, or 20 Students. I thought about using a while loop using SQL Server to obtain this data, or a temp table that aggregates the keys, but I want to know if there is any way using standard SQL to accomplish this, so that the script can be portable.

Notes: I know the output format is not ideal, but the only other option is that we will have to pull a different record for each Class/Student combo, and then will have to aggregate the id's separately.

Comment: What variety of SQL? MySQL has GROUP_CONCAT() for example. Also, how will you be using this once it's been generated? We may be able to give alternative processes.

Comment: @Dems Unfortunately the SQL variety varies, almost always either Oracle or a version of SQL Server though

Comment: @Dems Also, using the export as a way to receive the data in a standardized format, unfortunately using an additional export like "class_student" is not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different RDBMS have different ways to perform this kind of query.

If you are using MySQL, you should take a look at the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function.

In Firebird, you have the [`LIST`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-aggrfunc-list.html) aggregate function.

If you are using SQL Server, there are some answered questions in SO under the [sql-server-group-concat](/questions/tagged/sql-server-group-concat). The usual approach is using the `FOR XML PATH` construct. A good example is this: [SQL Query to get aggregated result in comma seperators along with group by column in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344950/sql-query-to-get-aggregated-result-in-comma-seperators-along-with-group-by-colum)

There are a few ways of doing that in Oracle, there's a good article [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php).

Answer (score 1):

If it's SQL Server, I tend to do it like this:

```
SELECT c.classID, c.other columns,
STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(varchar,StudentID) 
    FROM StudentClass sc where c.ClassId = sc.ClassID
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as StudentIdList
from ClassTable c
```

This assumes that you have a `ClassTable` which has an ID of `ClassId` and also a `StudentClass` linking table which contains both `StudentId` and `ClassId`.

EDIT: You must have some kind of table with both student and class information so the two are linked together. Either a linking table or if each student is only allowed one class, then maybe the `ClassId` is stored in the student table. Either way, the above should help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: no, it can't be done in standard SQL.

This is because you are trying to put multiple values into a single field, which is a violation of first normal form.

You could do it using non-standard sql, but the sql would be different for each database.

However, you could also do it using a tablix in SSRS (which could use the same standard SQL to access the tables in both Oracle and SQLServer).