# How to combine values in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure

```
SELECT P.Name,P.Description,
      PP.Attribute,PD.Value
FROM admin.Profiles P
LEFT JOIN admin.ProfilePreferenceMap PPM on P.ProfileID=PPM.ProfileID
LEFT JOIN admin.ProfilePrefDtl PD on PD.ProfilePrefDtlID=PPM.PreferenceID
LEFT JOIN admin.ProfilePref PP on PP.ProfilePrefID=PD.ProfilePrefID
WHERE P.Name='Profile1'
```

which returns the rows like

```
Name          Description           Attribute  Value
Profile1    Profile 1 description     E         EV
Profile1    Profile 1 description     S         SV
```

I would like to get the result as

```
Name            Description         Attribute   Value
Profile1    Profile 1 description   E,S         EV,SV
```

My purpose is to convert this values to JSON data like -

```
[{"Name":"Profile1","Description":"Profile 1 description","Attribute":["E", "S"],"Value":["EV", "SV"]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [emulate GROUP_CONCAT() which exists in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344950/sql-query-to-get-aggregated-result-in-comma-seperators-along-with-group-by-colum?lq=1)

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/869ad/2)

```
with t as
(
  SELECT P.Name,P.Description,
      PP.Attribute,PD.Value
  FROM admin.Profiles P
  LEFT JOIN admin.ProfilePreferenceMap PPM on P.ProfileID=PPM.ProfileID
  LEFT JOIN admin.ProfilePrefDtl PD on PD.ProfilePrefDtlID=PPM.PreferenceID
  LEFT JOIN admin.ProfilePref PP on PP.ProfilePrefID=PD.ProfilePrefID
  WHERE P.Name='Profile1'
)

select 
    Name,Description, 
    stuff((select ', ' + Attribute 
           from t t2 where t1.NAme = t2.NAme and t1.Description = t2.Description
           for xml path('')),
          1,2,'') [Attributes],
    stuff((select ', ' + Value
           from t t2 where t1.NAme = t2.NAme and t1.Description = t2.Description
           for xml path('')),
          1,2,'') [Values]
from t t1
group by Name,Description
```

Comment: **[Similar to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server/273330#273330)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use `group by` to group by unique name or description column but i'm not sure there is a easy way to get the comma separated value, made of values across separate rows, unless you did something with `Temp` tables and `CONCAT()` possibly?

If grouping is ok try this:

```
SELECT P.Name,P.Description,
      PP.Attribute,PD.Value
FROM admin.Profiles P
LEFT JOIN admin.ProfilePreferenceMap PPM on P.ProfileID=PPM.ProfileID
LEFT JOIN admin.ProfilePrefDtl PD on PD.ProfilePrefDtlID=PPM.PreferenceID
LEFT JOIN admin.ProfilePref PP on PP.ProfilePrefID=PD.ProfilePrefID
WHERE P.Name='Profile1'
GROUP BY P.Name
```

However, grouping like this will only show the first row (based on sort) of your `Attribute` and `Value` columns howe

Comment: it will throw error .. `column attribute, value not in group by or aggregate function`

Comment: 'group by' is not the way I am looking for, because actually I only listed out 4 fields, in real they are more than 15. Its not possible to give aggregate function for each!