# Trying to combine multiple rows from a table into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-group-concat

I've been trying to figure this out for a little bit now and i keep running into dead ends.  Maybe someone here can help me.  I work for a company and we are going to be receiving a file for units we are going to repair.  In certain situations, we receive one claim for repair that has multiple units contained within it.  I only have one field to import the serial number and I need to combine how ever many rows there is for a specific claim.

For example the file I would get would look like:

```
ClaimNumber       SerialNumber
555                12345
555                123456
555                1234567
556                4321
557                3421
558                9876
558                98765
```

So i need to export this table combining the serial numbers into one field like:

```
ClaimNumner       SerialNumber
555                12345, 123456, 1234567
556                4321
557                3421
558                9876, 98765
```

I am limited on receiving the file in this format, so this is all i have to work with.  There are other fields in the file but i think these are the ones that I should be looking at.  let me know if anyone has any ideas.  Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Comment: What is the real delimiter between the columns in the file? Is it a comma, a tab, 8 spaces, can I make any other guesses?

Comment: The file that i receive from them is comma delimited

Comment: So is your problem in translating the data, or is your problem also getting the file into the database in the first place?

Comment: Why are you not creating a new normalized table for the serial number? What you are asking to do sounds like it's going to limit the use of that information going forward...

Comment: I can get the file into the database no problem and test different queries on it and everything.  Just cant seem to get it into the format that i need.  I tried using string concatenation but since my query returns more than one serial number it always errors out.

Comment: @user2867287 then did you look at [the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server), which has working examples, instead of trying off-the-cuff stuff on your own?

Comment: @user2867287 See either the referenced dup above or -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344950/sql-query-to-get-aggregated-result-in-comma-seperators-along-with-group-by-colum - this has been asked many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your table is named Claim, then I think this should do it, (not tested)

```
Select Main.ClaimNumber,
   Left(Main.Serials,Len(Main.Serials)-1) As "Serials" From(Select distinct T2.ClaimNumber, 
       (Select T1.SerialNumber + ',' AS [text()]
        From Claim T1
        Where T1.ClaimNumber = T2.ClaimNumber
        ORDER BY T1.ClaimNumber
        For XML PATH ('')) [Serials]
 From Claim T2) [Main]
```