# create delimited string from table1 depend table 2

Tags: sql

my table1 is :

### T1

```
col1    col2
 A1     C1,C2
 A2     C3,C5,C6
 A3     C4
 A4     C2,C5
```

and so table 2:

### T2

```
col1    col2        col3
 A1     C1          reaction
 A1     C2          accept
 A2     C5          reaction
 A2     C6          manager
 A4     C2          manager
```

how to result this?:

### query result

```
col1      col2
 A1       reaction,accept
 A2       NULL,reaction,manager
 A3       NULL
 A4       manager,NULL
```

please help me?

Comment: How is this different than your previous question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507239/join-comma-delimited-data-column

Answer (score 3):

### Never, never, never store multiple values in one column.

Like you see now this will only give you headaches. Normalize your table `T1`. Then you can join normally.

It should look like this

```
col1    col2
 A1     C1
 A1     C2
 A2     C3
 A2     C5
 A2     C6
 A3     C4
 A4     C2
 A4     C5
```

Comment: +1, though I think one never is missing. ;)

Comment: Yes. It's not atomic!

Comment: He has used `GROUP_CONCAT` directly as a data structure. :)

Comment: Null value very important

Comment: my means: i want exactly result query.