# How to specify optional OUTER JOIN condition in Oracle 8i

Tags: sql, oracle

Following code works in Oracle version >=  9i as displayed in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ddf2e/6)

```
SELECT  T1.col1, T1.col3,count(T2.col1)
FROM    T1
LEFT JOIN T2
    ON T1.col3 = T2.col3
    AND ',' || T2.col2 || ',' like '%,' || T1.col1 || ',%'
GROUP BY T1.col1, T1.col3
```

However based on [Oracle Left Outer Join](http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_left_outer_join.htm) article it seems like the `LEFT JOIN` is not available in `Oracle 8i` – and unfortunately I am working in 8i.

For `=` operator I know the equivalent code

```
SELECT  T1.col1, T1.col3
FROM    T1
, T2
WHERE T1.col3 = T2.col3 (+)
--AND ',' || T2.col2 || ',' like '%,' || T1.col1 || ',%'
```

**QUESTION**

But how can we specify the OUTER JOIN condition for the `LIKE` operator.

Note:  I believe, without the `(+)`, it will behave as INNER JOIN for that column.

**UPDATE**

Following query gives `ORA-00920: invalid relational operator` error

```
SELECT  T1.col1, T1.col3,count(T2.col1)
FROM    T1
,T2
WHERE     T1.col3 = T2.col3(+)
    AND (',' || T2.col2 || ',') LIKE ('%,' || T1.col1 || ',%')(+)
GROUP BY T1.col1, T1.col3
```

Comment: See the results of [First Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ae4a/1) and [Second Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ae4a/4). I need to list all the records present in T1  (irrespective of whether they are present in T2 or not).

Comment: I think Oracle 8i was released on 1998 based on [Oracle release dates](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_release_dates.htm) and it should be good enough to meet my requirement.

Comment: Working Code - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ae4a/10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create subqueries containing the modified columns and then joining the tables as below:

```
Select  Mt1.T1_Col1, Mt1.T1_Col3,Count(Mt2.T2_Col1)
From
  (Select T1.Col1 As T1_Col1, T1.Col3 As T1_Col3, '%,' || T1.Col1 || ',%' As T1_Col1_New     From T1) Mt1, 
  (Select T2.Col1 As T2_Col1, T2.Col2 As T2_Col2, T2.Col3 As T2_Col3, ',' || T2.Col2 || ',' As T2_Col2_New From T2) Mt2
Where Mt1.T1_Col3 = Mt2.T2_Col3 (+)
And Mt1.T1_Col1_New Like Mt2.T2_Col2_New (+)
Group By Mt1.T1_Col1, Mt1.T1_Col3;
```

I combined inline subqueries and outer joins here.

References:

1. http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Inline_view
2. http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ansi-iso-sql-support.php

Comment: Looks promising [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ae4a/6). Can you please add some references to such a solution (from Stack Overflow preferably)?

Answer (score 0):

Following is working code from [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ae4a/10)

```
Select  Mt1.T1_Col1, Mt1.T1_Col3,Count(Mt2.T2_Col1)
From
  (Select T1.Col1 As T1_Col1,
          T1.Col3 As T1_Col3,
          '%,' || T1.Col1 || ',%' As T1_Col1_New
   From T1) Mt1
,
  (Select T2.Col1 As T2_Col1,
          T2.Col2 As T2_Col2,
          T2.Col3 As T2_Col3,
          ',' || T2.Col2 || ',' As T2_Col2_New 
   From T2) Mt2
WHERE Mt1.T1_Col3 = Mt2.T2_Col3 (+)
And Mt2.T2_Col2_New (+) LIKE Mt1.T1_Col1_New
--Mt2 should be on the left side of LIKE
Group By Mt1.T1_Col1, Mt1.T1_Col3;
```

Answer (score -1):

I know you don't want to hear this, but as soon as anyone says they are using a version of Oracle <10g, the answer to any question they have to ask is "upgrade". In 2014 there is absolutely no good reason to be using Oracle 8.

Comment: I think Oracle 8i was released on 1998 based on [Oracle release dates](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_release_dates.htm) and it should be good enough to meet my requirement.

Comment: I think there is a workaround - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ae4a/6 as per @Joseph B

Comment: While it's easy to make a blanket statement like that, you know nothing of their particular situation.  There may be quite valid reasons they're still on 8i.