# SQL Server - write query that normalizes comma separated values in a poorly constructed schema

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-normalization

Problem: I am querying a poorly normalized database (I have no say in the design of the data and cannot change it)

Given the following database:

```
------------------------------------------
|      Name      |         Codes          |
------------------------------------------
|       Josh     |    A2A-8292            |
-------------------------------------------
|       Adam     |    D2C-1292, B2A-7292  |
-------------------------------------------
|       Jery     |    A2A-1292, F2A-2292, | 
|                |    C2A-2292            |
-------------------------------------------
```

How can I write a query that returns the normalized version e.g:

```
 ------------------------------------------
|      Name      |         Codes          |
------------------------------------------
|       Josh     |    A2A-8292            |
-------------------------------------------
|       Adam     |    D2C-1292            |
-------------------------------------------
|       Adam     |    B2A-7292            |
-------------------------------------------
|       Jery     |    A2A-1292            |
-------------------------------------------
|       Jery     |    F2A-2292            |
-------------------------------------------
|       Jery     |    C2A-2292            |
-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? Based on that, you might get a different answer.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas 2012

Comment: Is the number of characters per code fixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [join comma delimited data column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507239/join-comma-delimited-data-column)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use a TVF, here's another option

**Example**

```
Select A.Name 
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B2.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(Codes,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as B1
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B2(i)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Name    RetSeq  RetVal
Josh    1       A2A-8292
Adam    1       D2C-1292
Adam    2       B2A-7292
Jery    1       A2A-1292
Jery    2       F2A-2292
Jery    3       C2A-2292
```

Comment: Cheeky solution there, creating an XML doc on the fly. I haven't seen that one before. +1 for adding an arrow to my quiver.

Comment: @EricBrandt I was slow to adopt XML.  I was foolish.   You'd be surprised at the possibilities.

Comment: For the record, I'm still in the "yeah, maybe I should start taking it seriously" phase myself.

Answer (score 0):

Taking string split function from this answer: [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string)

You could run your query as following:

```
SELECT T.Name, X.*
FROM TABLE AS T
CROSS APPLY dbo.splitstring(Codes) AS X;
```