# get values in a column sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get values in column (item_name) and put it to another column(items_ordered) in another table

i tried the basic codes but it doesn't work (the usual insert sql)

tablename:mycart

```
+------+----------------+
| item_name |  Client   |
+------+----------------+
|  item1    |    wev    |
|  item2    |    wev    |
|  item3    |    wev    |
+------+----------------+
```

tablename:orders

```
+------+--------------------+
| items_ordered |  Client   |
+------+--------------------+
|               |           |
+------+--------------------+
```

what I want it to be is like this:

tablename:orders

```
+------+--------------------------+
| items_ordered       |  Client   |
+------+--------------------------+
| item1,item2,item3   |   wev     |
+------+--------------------------+
```

Code i used:

```
$sqlb = "select * from mycart where client='" . $_SESSION['fname'] . "'"; 

$resultb = $conn->query($sqlb); 

while($rowb = $resultb->fetch_assoc()){ 
    $rowb['item_name'] . ', ' ; 
    $client=$rowb['client']; 
    $sql_insertInto_myCart = "INSERT INTO orders(items,client) VALUES('$rowb','$client')"; 
    $query_sql_insertInto_myCart = $conn->query($sql_insertInto_myCart); 
    if(isset($query_sql_insertInto_myCart)) { 

    } 
}
```

Comment: try to use GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: but I think the "  while($rowb = $resultb->fetch_assoc()){ $rowb['item_name'] . ', ' ;  " part is wrong

Comment: @m. hernant
I'm sorry, I'm new to this, how do I use it with my current code?

Comment: Add code to your question not as comment

Comment: Why you want that output like your above result. @bae

Comment: i want it like that so I can display it together in a single card just by using echo

Comment: First of all you should not store values separated by comma, change your DB design. For example you should probably have orders with `client, order_id` fields and then a new table with `order_id, items` fields. There is an answer for [joining comma delimited data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507239/join-comma-delimited-data-column) that could help you in getting a cleaner database.

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
select Client, GROUP_CONCAT(`item_name` separator ',') as `item_name` from mycart where client='" . $_SESSION['fname'] . "'";
```

***Important Note:-***

Saving `,` separated data is against NORMALIZATION, so usually don't do that. Because it's become very hard to do CRUD operation on those records [as well as search too]

You need to use `prepared statement` to prevent your query from SQL INJECTION.

[mysqli::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

[PDO::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: THANK YOU, as always guys. love the help.

Comment: yes, I will. Any and every advice would help. thankssss

Answer (score 1):

You need to design your database schema according to normalization principles.

Then you would get something like this:

[image]