# How to select row/s from an other table using a comma-separated value from the first table?

Tags: sql

Is there any way to select row/s from an other table using a comma-separated value from the first table?

Table 1. `faculty`

| subject |
| --- |
| 101, 102 |
| 104 |
| 103, 105 |

Table 2. `subject`

| code | subject |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | subject 1 |
| 102 | subject 2 |
| 103 | subject 3 |
| 104 | subject 4 |
| 105 | subject 5 |

Expected Output:

| subject | subject |
| --- | --- |
| 101, 102 | subject 1, subject 2 |
| 104 | subject 4 |
| 103, 105 | subject 3, subject 5 |

I already tried this:

```
SELECT faculty.subject, subject_offered.code, subject_offered.subject 
       FROM faculty 
       LEFT JOIN subject_offered 
       ON subject_offered.code 
       IN (faculty.subject)
```

but the rows from `faculty` with multiple values (comma-separated) shows NULL in the code and subject column in `subject` table.

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b5a4.png)

Comment: The most ideal way to express your schema / sample table data is to create a sql fiddle.  Then volunteers can immediately play with **real** data and confidently post answers.  [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/2943403)  How about `FIND_IN_SET()`?  I can't imagine that you are the first person on Stack Overflow to ask how to overcome this "poor table design" challenge.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?  I don't see that mentioned anywhere in the question.

Comment: The **real solution** is of course to change your data model. Don't store comma separated values, when you are interested in the separate values. This is against database normalization and is just not how to use a relational database. Writing queries will become easier when you fix this. They will also be faster in general. And the DBMS will be able to guarantee data consistency (i.e. that the IDs you find in the set really exist).

Comment: my bad, I'm using SQL server. I appreciate your suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t1.subject, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.subject)
FROM faculty t1
JOIN subjects t2 ON FIND_IN_SET(t2.code, t1.subject)
GROUP BY t1.subject;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3e40ab353ff1e0a1cde678225fa63ed2

Comment: I didn't know `FIND_IN_SET` function, this answer is much simpler and clearer than mine. Great work!

Comment: @ThangLeQuoc The only possible problem - one who uses CSV in string column may add excess spaces after commas (for some beauty, maybe?) which will need in removing this space symbols before applying FIND_IN_SET.

Comment: I suggest not to use alias names like this. Alias names are supposed to make a query easier to read. This is the case with mnemonic names, such as f for faculty and s for subject. It is not the case for arbitrary names like t1 and t2. Just the opposite, such alias names can make a query much harder to read than it was without them.

Answer (score 2):

### Updated

Please see [the answer by @Akina](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69717605/5668956) for a complete correct and cleaner solution.

Although this is a very poor table design, there's still a way to get around this.

**Solution**

```sql
SELECT faculty_subject AS faculty_subject_codes, GROUP_CONCAT(subject ORDER BY code ASC) AS subjects
FROM (
  SELECT faculty.subject as faculty_subject, subject.*
FROM subject
JOIN faculty 
ON faculty.subject LIKE CONCAT('%', subject.code, '%')
) fa GROUP BY faculty_subject;
```

Give

| faculty_subject_codes | subjects |
| --- | --- |
| 101,102 | subject 1,subject 2 |
| 103,105 | subject 3,subject 5 |
| 104 | subject 4 |

Checkout [my fiddle for your question](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dwBwNENqBtywdgqB9LYaZu/1)

#### Explanation

Since the `faculty.subject` is a comma separated values, so you cannot do a regular join by `subject.code`, the work around is to use a `JOIN` with `LIKE` clause instead.

```sql
SELECT faculty.subject as faculty_subject, subject.*
FROM subject
JOIN faculty 
ON faculty.subject LIKE CONCAT('%', subject.code, '%');
```

| faculty_subject | code | subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101,102 | 101 | subject 1 |
| 101,102 | 102 | subject 2 |
| 103,105 | 103 | subject 3 |
| 104 | 104 | subject 4 |
| 103,105 | 105 | subject 5 |

Now we have multiple rows with the same faculty_subject , e.g for code 103 and 105. The next thing is to combine those duplicated row into a single entry, we will do this with a `GROUP CONCAT` statement, and `GROUP BY` the `faculty_subject`

```sql
SELECT faculty_subject AS faculty_subject_codes, GROUP_CONCAT(subject ORDER BY code ASC) AS subjects
FROM (
  SELECT faculty.subject as faculty_subject, subject.*
FROM subject
JOIN faculty 
ON faculty.subject LIKE CONCAT('%', subject.code, '%')
) fa GROUP BY faculty_subject;
```

Comment: Errorneous. Add `(10, 'subject 6')`... https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dwBwNENqBtywdgqB9LYaZu/2

Comment: Yeah true @Akina, I'm still thinking how to solve this, probably your solution is the best then...

Comment: Formally `ON CONCAT(',', faculty.subject, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', subject.code, ',%')` may fix - but it is excessively complex.

Comment: Great! I just dont get why the subject column shows only one subject and repeats itself based on the number of values in the faculty_subject column in my device, but it works fine in the sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT  f.subject,
            GROUP_CONCAT(s.subject  ) as subject
    FROM    faculty as f
    INNER JOIN subjects s
        ON FIND_IN_SET(s.code, f.subject) 
    GROUP BY f.subject;
```

[Run in Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34d16d/12)

Comment: How do you know that the OP is using SQL Server?  Are you sitting in the same room as them?

Comment: @mickmackusa Well, my apology. Obviously, you are right about this.

Comment: This answer looks A LOT like the bottom of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16508385/2943403

Comment: The question is MySQL-tagged, not SQL Server.

Comment: mickmackusa & Akina Thank you, for pointing it out. My apology. I have updated my answer to MySql

Comment: @TBA, did you edit your entire answer ( previously written in SQL server), and completely replace it with the answer from @Akina? This is literally stealing.

Comment: @ThangLeQuoc no way...I didn't even notice that Akina replied! I will never ever think about doing this that too in the same question :|