# Get rows from different table in a column in select query

Tags: sql-server

I want to be able to see the rows from different table in a single column .

Just like this question [How to select row/s from an other table using a comma-separated value from the first table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69717300/how-to-select-row-s-from-an-other-table-using-a-comma-separated-value-from-the-f) (which is a duplicate of this question: [MySQL Join two tables with comma separated values :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69717300/how-to-select-row-s-from-an-other-table-using-a-comma-separated-value-from-the-f)) but for Sql Server.

Tables from link:

Table 1. `faculty`

| subject |
| --- |
| 101, 102 |
| 104 |
| 103, 105 |

Table 2. `subject`

| code | subject |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | subject 1 |
| 102 | subject 2 |
| 103 | subject 3 |
| 104 | subject 4 |
| 105 | subject 5 |

Expected Output:

| subject | subject |
| --- | --- |
| 101, 102 | subject 1, subject 2 |
| 104 | subject 4 |
| 103, 105 | subject 3, subject 5 |

Basically I don't want to see multiple columns for joins but all corresponding values in on column comma separated.

Comment: Please show us your database schema, some sample data, and the query you have worked on so far.

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? Please also provide sample data and desired results. Trying to write sql for a generic concept like splitting rows to columns and string aggregating post-join isn't easy.

Comment: @JNevill my problem is the same as above link. I have replaced Group_Concat with string_concat but Find_in_set doesn't exist in SqlServer , so I can't follow the answer..

Comment: Just FYI. I edited the question to link to the linked-duplicate and pulled through relevant information for the next person to stumble on this question and all the important bits will be here.

Answer (score 2):

To split a delimited string into rows in newer versions of sql server you can use `STRING_SPLIT()` in a CROSS APPLY. Then after joining, to aggregate strings back into delimited form you can use function `STRING_AGG`. Putting the same pieces together as the linked question you will get the following. NOTE that this requires newer versions of sql server that support both STRING_AGG and STRING_SPLIT functionality.

```
With faculty_split AS 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM faculty
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT (subject, ',') fac
)
SELECT faculty_split.subject as codes, STRING_AGG(subject.subject, ',') as subjects 
FROM faculty_split 
   INNER JOIN subject on faculty_split.value = subject.code
GROUP BY faculty_split.subject
```

[Link to fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e78be657a0be6bcadc121098b9a1087b)