# sql table from set of rows to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, set, sql-server-group-concat

My problem is straight forward:

i keep trying to transform the output of a table from

```
1 a
1 b     into    1 a b c
1 c

2 d
2 e     into    2 d e f
2 f
```

The table will have always sets of 3 rows that will become a table with 4 columns like above.

I tried looping and got stuck…

EDIT: is for SQL_SERVER

Comment: What RDBMS? my_SQL, SQL_SERVER? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

For MY_SQL

```
SELECT A, group_concat(B SEPARATOR " ") as BResult
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY A
```

- For ORACLE Look at List_Agg or WM_CONCAT or over order by if order of B is important.
- For SQL SERVER look at for XML Path.

However if you're simply trying to transform rows to columns...

you can use a cte if your dbms supports it.
you can look at pivots. if your rdbms supports  it.

Comment: im using sql server...i'll try your solution to see if it works

Comment: it won't the case operator assumed like data or some sort of type to define which data when to which column.  Wihtout it there's no way to make it work.

Comment: To make it work you'd have to use a pseudo_column like Row_Number and order by A then B and then somehow evaluate rows 1,4,7,10 etc (+3 each time) and then 2, 5,8,11 (+3 each time) and then ... if no type exists for each separate row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FOR XML PATH` construct to emulate MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` like this:

```
select 
    ID, 
    stuff((select ' ' + Value 
           from YourTable t2 where t1.ID = t2.ID 
           for xml path('')),
          1,2,'') [Values]
from YourTable t1
group by ID
```

Other answers on the topic:

- [SQL comma-separated row with Group By clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448734/sql-comma-separated-row-with-group-by-clause/7449137#7449137)
- [SQL Query to get aggregated result in comma seperators along with group by column in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344950/sql-query-to-get-aggregated-result-in-comma-seperators-along-with-group-by-colum/6348414#6348414)