# Retrieving Data from Multiple Tables base on id

Tags: mysql, inner-join

With php I am trying to get data from 2 different tables :

```
Table : products

+-------+---------+----------+
| pcode | product | category |
+-------+---------+----------+
| 1     | jeans   | men      |
+-------+---------+----------+
| 2     | shirt   | men      |
+-------+---------+----------+


Table : colors
+-------+---------+
| pcode | colors  | 
+-------+---------+
| 1     | blue    |
+-------+---------+
| 1     | black   |
+-------+---------+
| 1     | white   |
+-------+---------+
| 2     | yellow  |
+-------+---------+

Result I want should be like :

+-------+---------+----------+---------------------+
| pcode | product | category | colors              |
+-------+---------+----------+---------------------+
| 1     | jeans   | men      | black, blue, white  |
+-------+---------+----------+---------------------+
| 2     | shirt   | men      | yellow              |
+-------+---------+----------+---------------------+
```

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Vikram

Comment: Hi Vijay - sorry I forgot to mention - it is mysql.

Comment: Did you try anything already?

Comment: I tried inner join & left join but result am getting is 3 rows for pcode 1

Comment: I recommend you edit the original question to add this info, and how the rows looked like (when it didn't work). Unfortunatelly I cannot help with the question, but it'd make the people who sees the question and can help more eager to do so.

Comment: This has been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448734/sql-comma-separated-row-with-group-by-clause

Comment: Franciso - I got pissed of it for long hours - so finally posted here - will take care of it next time - thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mihai's Query also working..

Can also try this..

```
select p.*, group_concat(colors separator ',') colors from products p left outer join colors c on p.pcode=c.pcode group by p.pcode;
```

Comment: wow! It works fine - but one issue now I got is - suppose pcode 3 items does not have any color options - it wont show data for pcode 3 :(

Comment: SELECT p.pcode,product,category,GROUP_CONCAT(colors) as colors FROM products p left outer JOIN colors c  ON p.pcode=c.pcode  GROUP BY product;

Try this...

Comment: Yup - that works fine - wow!! superb - Thanks a tonne Balaji.

Comment: Glad that you got the result.. :)

Comment: Yup - got a perfect result. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi again - for getting data from 3 tables I tried :

<code>
"SELECT products.pcode, 
             products.product, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(c.colors) as c.colors,  
             GROUP_CONCAT(x.pimages) as x.pimages
             FROM products p JOIN
             colors c ON c.pcode=p.pcode
             pimages x ON x.pcode=p.pcode 
             GROUP BY product;"

</code>
But did not work :(.

Comment: SELECT products.pcode, products.product, GROUP_CONCAT(c.colors) as c.colors, GROUP_CONCAT(x.pimages) as x.pimages FROM products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN colors c ON c.pcode=p.pcode LEFT OUTER JOIN pimages x ON x.pcode=p.pcode GROUP BY product; try this

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Balaji - but it did not worked :(

Comment: SELECT products.pcode, products.product, GROUP_CONCAT(c.colors) as colors, GROUP_CONCAT(x.pimages) as pimages FROM products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN colors c ON c.pcode=p.pcode
LEFT OUTER JOIN pimages x ON x.pcode=p.pcode
GROUP BY p.product; Try this

Comment: SELECT products.pcode, products.product, GROUP_CONCAT(c.colors) as colors, GROUP_CONCAT(x.pimages) as pimages FROM products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN colors c ON c.pcode=p.pcode
LEFT OUTER JOIN pimages x ON x.pcode=p.pcode
GROUP BY p.product; Try this

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p.pcode,product,category,GROUP_CONCAT(colors) as colors
FROM products p JOIN colors c 
ON p.pcode=c.pcode 
GROUP BY product
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:You could try to use PDO or MySqli libary(links bellow) to run this SQL Statement

You could try this SQL statement i think it will do the job but will show the rows in a different way that you requested just give it a try:

```
SELECT colors.pcode , products.products ,products.category ,  colors.colors
FROM colors
INNER JOIN FIRST ON colors.pcode = products.pcode
```

Results:
[image: The result]

Or if you wanted like you asked you should seperate the work in multiple SQL Satatement:

```
SELECT colors FROM colors WHERE pcode = 1
```

And with some SQL Sattement get all the colors
Then get the products and the productsand categorys this way:

```
SELECT product , category FROM products WHERE pcode = 1
```

And also with some like this you will get all what you need

But i would prefer the first one as it is more handy and faster.

Links:

PDO:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

MYSQLI:

http://www.php.net/mysqli

Have a nice day :)