# Duplicate records as comma separated columns in SQL

Tags: sql

```
VillageId     MDL        Village         PINCode
```

---

```
101           A1           ABC           505330
102           A1           DEF           505330
103           A1           CDF           505330
104           A2           LMN           505331
105           A2           KLM           505331
106           A4           RST           623212
```

I want to show duplicate records as a comma separated column in result. Duplicate record here are
where MDL and PINCODE both should match.

```
 MDL           Village           PINCode
---------------------------------------------
  A1          ABC,DEF,CDF         505330
  A2           LMN,KLM            505331
  A4            RST               623212
```

So far i tried writing a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ListComma 
( 
     @PINCode varchar(11),
    @MDL varchar(MAX)

) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @r VARCHAR(8000) 
      SELECT @r = ISNULL(@r+', ', '') +  Village 
      FROM dbo.tblVillageData
      WHERE MDL= @MDL
        and PINCODE = @PINCode   
    RETURN @r 
END
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL comma-separated row with Group By clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448734/sql-comma-separated-row-with-group-by-clause)

Answer (score 4):

**SQL Server:**

Using `STUFF` and `XML Path` you could do this easily:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MDL
    ,STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + t1.Village
            FROM dbo.tblVillageData T1
            WHERE T1.MDL = T2.MDL
              AND T1.PINCode = T2.PINCode
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS Village
    ,PINCode
FROM dbo.tblVillageData T2;
```

[**SQL Server Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be47a/6/0)

**MySQL:**

If you are using MySQL database, then you could simply use `GROUP_CONCAT` to do this:

```
SELECT 
     MDL
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(Village) AS Village
    ,PINCode
FROM Test T2
GROUP BY MDL;
```

[**MySQL Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be47a/7/0)

**Update:**

If you have multiple repeating `Village` value like you provided in the comment, you could easily handle them using `distinct` within the subquery:

```
SELECT Distinct  MDL
    ,STUFF((
            SELECT distinct ',' + t1.Village   --add distinct here
            FROM Test T1
            WHERE T1.MDL = T2.MDL
              AND T1.PINCode = T2.PINCode
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS Village
    ,PINCode
FROM Test T2;
```

[**Duplicates Village Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed88a/3/0)

Comment: thanks for ur help, sorry i saw ur answer lately. May be i am failed in explaining u correctly. Lets say i have following records http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed88a/2 . In this case a single row should come with village ABC, LMN, KLM

Comment: @user3452210 Please check out my updated answer. It should handle your duplicate village values. :)