# occurrence of values in a row

Tags: sql

I need SQL code for below issue

I have two table as shown below

```
Id  |Name
1   |Roy
1   |Roy
1   |Roy
1   |Roy
1   |Roy



Name    Type
Roy |    GE
Roy |    RA
Roy |    SA
Roy |    PA
Roy |    PA
```

These two tables have primary key Name.

Desired output

```
Id  Type
1 | GE,RA,SA,PA
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS (`MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Both DBMS's are different. So, tag only that you are really using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Comment: Also version number plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **Oracle**:

```
SELECT A.ID, LISTAGG(B."type", ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY B.NAME) "TYPE"
FROM 
(SELECT T1.NAME, T1.ID
FROM T1
GROUP BY T1.NAME, T1.ID) A
JOIN 
(SELECT T2.NAME, T2."type"
FROM T2
GROUP BY T2.NAME, T2."type") B
ON A.NAME = B.NAME
GROUP BY A.ID;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3fd0c01bff731bde39c000eb6cb8769d) for **Oracle**.

If you are using **SQLServer**:

```
SELECT A.ID, STRING_AGG (B."type", ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY B.NAME) "TYPE"
FROM 
(SELECT T1.NAME, T1.ID
FROM T1
GROUP BY T1.NAME, T1.ID) A
JOIN 
(SELECT T2.NAME, T2."type"
FROM T2
GROUP BY T2.NAME, T2."type") B
ON A.NAME = B.NAME
GROUP BY A.ID;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2493165a671d46110208a05e587bd007) for **SQLServer**.

And if you are using **MySQL** then:

```
SELECT A.ID, GROUP_CONCAT(B.type ORDER BY B.NAME separator ',')
FROM 
(SELECT t1.NAME, t1.ID
FROM t1
GROUP BY t1.NAME, t1.ID) A
JOIN 
(SELECT t2.NAME, t2.`type`
FROM t2
GROUP BY t2.NAME, t2.`type`) B
ON A.NAME = B.NAME
GROUP BY A.ID;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=25ce82d8ce827767ded5a1665bf07d00) for **MySQL**

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to carry out two steps.

1. Join the two tables on name, select id and type. Your SQL will look something like:

   select id, type from table1, table2 where table1.name = table2.name
2. Use one of the solutions provided in [this excellent previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056834/duplicate-records-as-comma-separated-columns-in-sql) to collapse the duplicated column into a comma separated column depending on what your database is.

Answer (score 0):

The below code doesn't work unless the ID is unique. Please ignore this answer as explained in the comments.

```
select PersonName.Name, STRING_AGG(NameType.Type, ',') as 'Type' from PersonName
    left outer join NameType
    on PersonName.Name = NameType.Name
    Group by PersonName.Name
```

Explanation:
 1. Consider the first table as PersonName
 2. Second table as NameType
 3. Join the two tables on Name field/column
 4. Use STRING_AGG to Concatenate
 5. As it is an Aggregate function, you will need a group by Statement

Comment: Hi @Raja, your example is for SQLServer I believe. Well as you can see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a965ee6175882039fcc5bf53317399fc your query does not work. 1. It returns name and not Id as OP asked for. 2. It also returns multiple values for type. Hope this will help... Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. My bad. I thought the first table id column was a Primary key.

Comment: Hi Raja, Thanks for your response .. But i am getting error as "SQL Error [9829] [S0001]: STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation."

Comment: Hello @SriSri, so none of my examples helped ? I have sent you DEMO's where you can see how it works for every database specified and with your data! What seems to be problem there ? With my query's you get exactly you asked for...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for SQL:

```
select t1.Id, STRING_AGG(t2.Type, ',') as 'Type' from 
(select distinct ID, Person.PersonName from Person) t1
left outer join NameType t2
on t1.PersonName = t2.PersonName
Group by t1.Id
```

[image]

Comment: @Raha, I believe this solution will not remove the double type 'PA' that the OP has in his data. Check the demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0478f2e92bf2d04c19238370fc182577

Comment: Thanks for your response . But i m getting the error as "SQL Error [9829] [S0001]: STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation."