# Subquery returning csv written values in a Main Query Column, possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, join, sql-server-group-concat

I got to tables.

`TABLE 1: [..fields..] [CATEGORIE] [..fields..]`

`TABLE 2: [..fields..] [ID] [CATEGORIE] [..fields..]`

I want to connect a bit special and tried it like this:

`SELECT [..other fields..], CATEGORIE, (SELECT ID FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.CATEGORIE = TABLE1.CATEGORIE) FROM TABLE1;`

I want to have the IDs of the SubQuery in on Column of the Main Query

like that ( [] are representing columns)

[resultfield1] [resultfield2] [resultfield3] [ID1,ID2,ID3,ID4,...]

is there a way to afford it?

Help is very appreciated,

thanks in advance

Comment: This has been asked many many times before. Just do a quick search with the words GROUP, CONCATENATE and SQL-SERVER

Comment: @Lamak This has been asked so many times that I created the `sql-server-group-concat` tag. It's like the `greatest-n-per-group` tag. It keeps coming back.

Comment: thx @Lamak, I didn't know theese terms, but issue is solved after this answers / comments, thx to all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As hard as it is to read understand your question, what you want is to use `FOR XML PATH`:

```
select 
    categorie, 
    stuff((select ', ' + id
           from table2 t2 where t1.categorie = t2.categorie
           for xml path('')),
          1,2,'') [IDs]
from table1 t1
```

Further reading here:

- [SQL Query to get aggregated result in comma seperators along with group by column in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344950/sql-query-to-get-aggregated-result-in-comma-seperators-along-with-group-by-column/6348414#6348414)
- [SQL same unit between two tables needs order numbers in 1 cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624592/sql-same-unit-between-two-tables-needs-order-numbers-in-1-cell/5624663#5624663)

Comment: this is exactly the solution. Thank you!